# Creating a Tracking Pixel using Google Analytics v4 Measurement Protocol

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4, event-tracking, tracking-pixel

I'm trying to create a tracking pixel using Google Analytics 4.  From what I've read in the docs, you can only send a POST to create events.  Here is an example:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url 'https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect?api_secret=XXXXXXXXXX&measurement_id=G-XXXXXXXX' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{
    "client_id": "555",
    "events": [{
        "name": "test_event",
        "params": {
            "session_id": "123",
            "engagement_time_msec": "100"
        }
    }]
}'
```

This of course works.  However, I want to create a tracking pixel that I can use to track things like email opens via an HTTP GET (via the call from the <img />'s src).  With universal google analytics, this is done via:

`<img src="https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=G-XXXXXX&cid=555&t=event&ec=email&ea=open&dp=%2Femail%2Ftest&dt=test" alt="" height="1" width="1">`

Am I missing something here or is it no longer possible to create a tracking pixel like the one above, but for GA v4?

I even found a thread on [google's support page](https://support.google.com/analytics/thread/83908432/how-to-tracking-email-opens-and-clicks-in-ga4?hl=en) for this but no responses and has been locked.

I did try just adding a pixel like so, but no luck:

`<img src="https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=4&tid=G-XXXXXXXX&cid=555&t=event&ec=email&ea=open&dp=%2Femail%2Ftest&dt=test" alt="" height="1" width="1">`

I also tried using `https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect` in the img src, but http get is not allowed for that endpoint so it just errors out.

Comment: Try using v=2 for your new tracking pixel.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I resolved it by using the following code:

```
<img src="https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=2&tid=G-xxxxxxxxxx&cid=555&t=event&en=eventName">
```

Note it is v=2 and not v=1 or v=4.

Comment: but you are using the static cid 555 there, arent you? in that case the event wont be attributed to the proper GA user afaik. isnt it true?

Comment: if i use image tag in real time view i see no event. any idea how to fix if i test it on a website

Comment: @fvrab, i substitute the cid 555 to a unique user id if one exists.

Comment: @SebastianOffers you should see the event in real time.

Answer (score 1):

The Measurement Protocol is designed for use server side to send events. No pixel is used, just a POSTed message with a secret key. Note the key is secret, so should never be used on the client side.

If you are client-side on an HTML page, then you should use the normal gtag to send events.

Comment: Thanks Tony, that makes sense, but I'm working with emails.  From what I see you can't run javascript in an email, so I can't use gtag since it requires javascript.  This is where I am hung up with GA4, there appears to be no way to track events in img src anymore to track opens.  I feel as though this is so common yet appears to be completely missing in GA4 or I am not seeing something.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the email bit. You could invent your own endpoint on your own server and have the tracking pixel point there. Then have that endpoint forward to Google via the measurement protocol.

Comment: No worries, that's the only option that i'm seeing at this point.  Thank you again for helping out!

Comment: you can also work with an image for analytics but than you have only an counter to count the opening rate. The id is allways than the same like: https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=2&tid=G-XXXXXX&cid=555&t=event&en=emailOpenCrawle